# Bootstrap sidebar to mobile filter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, filter, sidebar

I am currently working on a bootstrap website where i have a sidebar(left) and the main content on the right. Now this is going perfect in desktop view, but when its seenable on mobile devices its all getting messed up,

How can i make my sidebar/filter area to a mobile version with a dropdown filter?

I want the filter area to be like an accordion that expands when you press the plus.

[image: image of the desktop view and how i would like it in mobile]

Hope someone can help me,

with friendly greetings

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the appropriate tags for everything. To make it mobile you want to add ** < div >** tags with the appropriate headers. < Div col-md-5 > for example would only allow that section to take up 5 columns of space on a medium view, typically a desktop.

**Make sure you have the column spans add up to 12 otherwise you wont be aligned.**

Here is a helpful link: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Broken link. Maybe this will help further readers (version 4.0): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/